# How to remove extra | (pipe) separator from rows when loading | (pipe)-separated text into R

Tags: r

I am reading text from a file in which the text is separated by | (pipes).

The text table looks like this (tweet id|date and time|tweet):

```
545253503963516928|Wed Dec 17 16:25:40 +0000 2014|Massachusetts Pharmacy Owners Arrested in Meningitis Deaths http://xxxxxxxxx
545235402156937217|Wed Dec 17 15:13:44 +0000 2014|For First Time, Treatment Helps Patients With Worst Kind of Stroke, Study Says http://xxxxxxxxx
```

I am reading this information using the following code:

```
nyt  <- read.table(file=".../nytimeshealth.txt", 
                                      sep="|", 
                                      header = F, 
                                      quote="", 
                                      fill=T, 
                                      stringsAsFactors = F,
                                      numerals ="no.loss",
                                      encoding = "UTF-8",
                                      na.strings = "NA")
```

Now, while most of the rows in the original file have 3 columns, each separated by a '|', a few of the rows have an additional '|' separator. That is to say, they have four columns, because some of the tweets themselves contain a `|` symbol.

```
545074589374881792|Wed Dec 17 04:34:43 +0000 2014|National Briefing | New England: Massachusetts: Sex-Change Surgery Denied to Inmate http://xxxxxxxxx
```

I know that using`fill=T` option in the `read.table` function above allows me to read rows of unequal length (blank fields are implicitly added in the empty cells).

So, the row above becomes

```
71 545074589374881792 Wed Dec 17 04:34:43 +0000 2014 National Briefing
72 New England: Massachusetts: Sex-Change Surgery Denied to Inmate http://xxxxxxxxx
```

However, now column 3 of row 71 has incomplete information, and columns 2 and 3 of row 72 are empty while column 1 does not contain the tweet ID but a part of the tweet. Is there any way I can avoid this? I would like to remove the extra `|` separator wherever it appears, so that I do not lose any information.

Is this possible while reading the text file into R? Or is it something I will have to take care of before I start loading the text. What would be my best course of action?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: point noted regarding the use of T and F for TRUE and FALSE. Please also see other comment about your suggested method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a text file called `text.txt` with the 3 lines you provide as example of your data (the 2 easy lines without any `|` in the tweet as well as the one which has a `|` inside the tweet).

Here is the content of this file:

```
545253503963516928|Wed Dec 17 16:25:40 +0000 2014|Massachusetts Pharmacy Owners Arrested in Meningitis Deaths http://xxxxxxxxx
545235402156937217|Wed Dec 17 15:13:44 +0000 2014|For First Time, Treatment Helps Patients With Worst Kind of Stroke, Study Says http://xxxxxxxxx
545074589374881792|Wed Dec 17 04:34:43 +0000 2014|National Briefing | New England: Massachusetts: Sex-Change Surgery Denied to Inmate http://xxxxxxxxx
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

readLines("text.txt", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  map(., str_split_fixed, "\\|", 3) %>%
  map_df(., as_tibble)
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  V1                 V2                            
  <chr>              <chr>                         
1 545253503963516928 Wed Dec 17 16:25:40 +0000 2014
2 545235402156937217 Wed Dec 17 15:13:44 +0000 2014
3 545074589374881792 Wed Dec 17 04:34:43 +0000 2014
  V3                                                                            
  <chr>                                                                         
1 Massachusetts Pharmacy Owners Arrested in Meningitis Deaths http://xxxxxxxxx  
2 For First Time, Treatment Helps Patients With Worst Kind of Stroke, Study Say…
3 National Briefing | New England: Massachusetts: Sex-Change Surgery Denied to …
```

Comment: but why not just join any extra columns ex post facto?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: Do you mean, split at every `|`, then join extra columns? That would work too. There are many solutions. I like this one because it is compact and avoids unnecessary steps (such as splitting to join again later)

Comment: This also works regardless of how many `|` you have in the tweets. So you don't have to worry about some tweets having more complex structures

Comment: @hrbrmstr: While the answer by prosoitos solves the issue, I would also like to know how to do this the other way? That is, by joining the columns. How would I go about joining column 3 of row 71 with column 1 of row 72, while discarding columns 2 and 3 of row 72. Furthermore, how do I check this in all lines that may be in this format (i.e., have more than 2 '|' separators) for the entire data frame? Thanks!

Comment: I posted a new answer to answer this question. But it is less nice because it will break if you have tweets which have more than one `|`. Or if you don't have any tweet with `|`. The 1st answer will always work, whether you have 0, 1, or more `|` in your tweets. Plus, it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, to get back to your comment and to use your initial code. But this solution will only work if you have one `|` per tweet (you can have tweets with none as long as at least one tweet has one `|`). If you don't have any `|` in your tweets, or if some tweets have more than one `|`, it will break and you will have to edit it. So the other answer, which will work regardless of the structure of your tweets is better IMO.

I am still using my `text.txt` file:

```
df <- read.table(file = "text.txt", 
                 sep = "|", 
                 header = F, 
                 quote = "", 
                 fill = T, 
                 stringsAsFactors = F,
                 numerals = "no.loss",
                 encoding = "UTF-8",
                 na.strings = "NA")

df %>%
  mutate(V3 = paste0(V3, V4)) %>%
  select(- V4)
```

**Result**

```
                  V1                             V2
1 545253503963516928 Wed Dec 17 16:25:40 +0000 2014
2 545235402156937217 Wed Dec 17 15:13:44 +0000 2014
3 545074589374881792 Wed Dec 17 04:34:43 +0000 2014
                                                                                                    V3
1 Massachusetts Pharmacy Owners Arrested in Meningitis Deaths http://xxxxxxxxx 
2 For First Time, Treatment Helps Patients With Worst Kind of Stroke, Study Says http://xxxxxxxxx 
3 National Briefing  New England: Massachusetts: Sex-Change Surgery Denied to Inmate http://xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @prosoitos. I am running into another problem: when using the read.table function, a row like this `585625669805219840|Wed Apr 08 02:10:14 +0000 2015|12 spring #superfoods – from leeks to beets: http://xxxxxxxx` appears as `585625669805219840 Wed Apr 08 02:10:14 +0000 2015 12 spring` All the text after the hastag `#superfoods` is not read into the data frame. This is true for other rows containing hashtags as well. Cannot understand why this would be the case.

Comment: That's because `#` is a comment in R. But if you use my first answer, you won't have this problem

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that...seems obvious now that you have mentioned it.

Comment: `read.table()` interprets your data. So anything after `#` is considered a comment and is thus omitted. `readLines()` however, read lines of strings as is, without any interpretation. So I really suggest that you use my first answer and forget about `read.table()` in your case. There are countless things that could go wrong with `read.table()` if you have funky characters in your tweets. While the `readLines()` answer is pretty bomb proof

Comment: thanks again, @prosoitos  `readLines()` does get around the problem of the hashtags. However, considering the same row, using readLines(), it is read as `12 spring #superfoods â€“ from leeks to beets: http:xxxxxxxx` The characters `â€“` show up instead of the `– ` symbol (I think it is an en dash). With read.table, I was able to handle situations like this using the `encoding = "UTF-8"` option (I think!). Any suggestions on how to work around this? Thanks!

Comment: Use the argument `encoding = "UTF-8"` within readLines. If you type `?readLines`, you will have access to the whole info on the function.

Comment: Was just going to write that... I did check `?readLines` and read that. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: You can also set `comment.char=""` in `read.table` - there's no need to abandon a whole function when this is documented in the help file.

Comment: Ah right. Good point. Thank you for pointing that out. I still think that the 1st answer is better though (much more compact and will not break with variable numbers of pipes)

Comment: I removed the section about `#` in my answer as you are correct that this was not a problem with this solution